# Image loads in simulator but not device?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiimageview

In Interface Builder, I have a UIImageView in a nib and have selected an image from the View Attributes pane.  The image loads fine in the simulator but not on my device in debug mode.  I don't get any errors.  Just no image.

I can see the particular image in my Target's Copy Bundle Resources folder.  Any ideas why it isn't showing on the device?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible cause: Iphone file system is case sensitive and MacOS is not. Try to check your image file name.