# Loading an image from a .png returns nil on device, fine in Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, ios-simulator

Some of them are working, but not all.
For example, on one screen I am loading 6 images from a file and displaying each of them inside a button. The first 4 are appearing but not the latter ones.

On my simulator (iPhone & iPad), all 6 display correctly.

A new view controller after that expects an array of images, but logging the array shows an empty array, whereas the simulator logs:

```
  self.images: (
"<UIImage: 0x5357270>",
"<UIImage: 0x5316d10>",
"<UIImage: 0x530dcd0>",
"<UIImage: 0x5345160>",
"<UIImage: 0x5345340>",
"<UIImage: 0x530dcd0>"
```

The file names are lower cased as are the strings to access them. (referenced from [Image loads in simulator but not device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853263/image-loads-in-simulator-but-not-device) )

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned off png compression, also reopened the images in photoshop and saved - discarding Fireworks data.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the images are copied into the project, not just referenced.

To do this, make a folder with all the images. Delete all the images in the app. Add Existing Files-> find the folder with all the images -> make sure the "copy into project" checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

On the iOS, the filenames should not have spaces I believe. Try removing spaces / or replacing them with underscores in your images.